# What could be the code for putting existing auto increment id in order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn more about SQL, now I see there is something, when I delete something from the table it leaves that id empty like if I delete 8 and then insert new data it creates id 10. But learned that it can be fixed by this code

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

But what I can't figure out, what if I have a table that contains id -16-17-18- and so on an on.

How do I make my SQL command to turn 16 into 1, 17 into 2, and 18 into 3.

Is there any code for that?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: "Aligning" a generated primary key is a useless task. The only thing that such a value has to be is unique. The value 8 is just as good as 42, 378934 or -4653. Don't bother if there are gaps.

Comment: i am using sql-server

Comment: i am sorry, MySql, newbie here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using that id for a relational lookup value in another table, you don't want to do this. Reordering your ids will scramble the relationships.

Also, you generally shouldn't be deleting anything from databases. It removes historical data that can't be retrieved.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159232/should-we-ever-delete-data-in-a-database

Doing what you're asking is only an effect of your OCD kicking in and wanting an Order To Everything. Databases don't care about that. The data type for the id should have enough numbers to reach a huge amount of rows before you have to think about reordering anything, and it'd be easier to simply turn an `int` to a `bigint` than reordering anything. In SQL Server, you need over 2 billion rows to have to worry about this. It's likely you'll have to worry about disk size of your server before you have to worry about this.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-data-types-reference/

Comment: i understand that, but what i want to know, if thats possible using sql-server to order ids the way they are supposed to be

Comment: Your use of "supposed to be" shows this is an OCD thing. I know because I too had it when I first working with databases. Reordering your IDs is such a major hassle that you aren't likely to find anyone willing to help you out with writing code to do it. Here's why: in a relational DB, you can't delete (change) an ID without your relations also changing first, but you don't know what the new ID is going to be without moving it. You'd likely have to delete all your child data, change your IDs, then re-insert your child data. This has the effect of moving your whole DB. Not safe or quick.